# Pivoting mysql result with dates and sums

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have some data in mysql that I need to create some reports from.
My data are coming from the following query :

```
SELECT StoreNbr,StoreName,Date, SUM(`Sales`) FROM sales_tbl GROUP BY StoreNbr,StoreName,Date;
```

This results in the following data (just a small subset for my example):

```
+-----------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| StoreNbr | StoreName              | Date       | SUM(Sales)        |
+-----------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
|      1112 | Store1                | 2016-01-16 |            115.09 |
|      1112 | Store1                | 2016-01-17 |             81.00 |
|      1113 | Store2                | 2016-01-16 |            112.44 |
|      1113 | Store2                | 2016-01-17 |             56.61 |
```

I would like to transform my data to be this way :

```
+-----------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| StoreNbr | StoreName              | 2016-01-16       | 2016-01-17  |
+-----------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
|      1112 | Store1                | 115.09           |       81.00 |
|      1113 | Store2                | 112.44           |       56.61 |
```

Obviously there might be thousands of rows (stores) and unknown number of dates to be returned in the query as my query might be run like this (this will need to return 120+ number of columns for dates):

```
SELECT StoreNbr,StoreName,Date, SUM(`Sales`) FROM sales_tbl WHERE (Date BETWEEN '2016-01-10' AND '2016-05-10') GROUP BY StoreNbr,StoreName,Date;
```

There are a few ways to do this, none very simple. I did some research and there are some that mention that mysql does not support pivoting. I am running mariadb though, and saw that mariadb supports pivoting through the connect engine. I was unable to make it work though (adjust their official examples on my data).
Another way is lots of IFs and Cases, but most of the answers I am finding are very difficult to adapt or are tailored only to the data the guy that asks provides.
Another approach would be to process the data as they come out on my array as I have a json response in the end that feeds a datatable. - This is another think I have not managed to figure out yet.

I am looking for a way to get the desired output independent on the amount of dates (and I guess dates could be replaced by weeks or whatever else). Can anyone help?

Comment: I doubt this could give a really nice report but the simplest solution would probably to use PHP which you listed in your tags.

Comment: I know! I am just executing company needs :) Makes sense though that marketing might want to see performance of a store over 5 days, and this data could be nicely used on a graph on screen or after the export to excel.

Comment: SQL is actually not a good reporting language.  It's an excellent data extraction language though.  So you should keep your current query and make a report based on it in another language like PHP.

Comment: Are there many various dates in your data?

Comment: there are reports that are pulled from multiple stores every day. so for example if i pull a report now, I will get yesterday's date with all sales for stores for that date. Those data are accumulated and are the data I am trying to report on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all distinct dates

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Date 
FROM sales_tbl 
WHERE (Date BETWEEN '2016-01-10' AND '2016-05-10')
ORDER BY Date;
```

and initialize an array which is indexed by that dates storing zeros:

```php
$dateIndexedArray = array();
while($row = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
    $dateIndexedArray[$row['Date']] = 0;
}
```

The arry will look like

```php
[
    '2016-01-16' => 0,
    '2016-01-17' => 0
]
```

Then execute your query

```sql
SELECT StoreNbr, StoreName,Date, SUM(`Sales`) AS Sales 
FROM sales_tbl
WHERE (Date BETWEEN '2016-01-10' AND '2016-05-10')
GROUP BY StoreNbr,StoreName,Date;
```

And store the "Sales" in a date indexed array per store

```php
$report = array();
while($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $storeIndex = $row['StoreNbr'] . ':' . $row['StoreName'];
    if (!isset($report[$storeIndex])) {
        $report[$storeIndex] = array(
            'StoreNbr'  => $row['StoreNbr'],
            'StoreName' => $row['StoreName'],
            'Sales' => $dateIndexedArray
        );
    }
    $report[$storeIndex]['Sales'][$row['Date']] = $row['Sales'];
}
```

The `$report` array will look like:

```php
[
    '1112:Store1' => [
        'StoreNbr'  => 1112,
        'StoreName' => 'Store1',
        'Sales' => [
            '2016-01-16' => 115.09,
            '2016-01-17' => 81.00
        ]
    ],
    '1113:Store2' => [
        'StoreNbr'  => 1113,
        'StoreName' => 'Store2',
        'Sales' => [
            '2016-01-16' => 112.44,
            '2016-01-17' => 56.61
        ]
    ]
]
```

**Update:**
If you need all data to be in one row for each store you can change the code to:

```php
$report = array();
while($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $storeIndex = $row['StoreNbr'] . ':' . $row['StoreName'];
    if (!isset($report[$storeIndex])) {
        $report[$storeIndex] = $dateIndexedArray;
        $report[$storeIndex]['StoreNbr']  = $row['StoreNbr'];
        $report[$storeIndex]['StoreName'] = $row['StoreName'];
    }
    $report[$storeIndex][$row['Date']] = $row['Sales'];
}
```

The resulting array will look like:

```
[
    '1112:Store1' => [
        'StoreNbr'  => 1112,
        'StoreName' => 'Store1'
        '2016-01-16' => 115.09,
        '2016-01-17' => 81.
    ],
    '1113:Store2' => [
        'StoreNbr'  => 1113,
        'StoreName' => 'Store2',
        '2016-01-16' => 112.44,
        '2016-01-17' => 56.61
    ]
]
```

**Update 2:** To get the total sales per store you can use `WITH ROLLUP`

```sql
SELECT StoreNbr, StoreName,Date, SUM(`Sales`) AS Sales 
FROM sales_tbl
WHERE (Date BETWEEN '2016-01-10' AND '2016-05-10')
GROUP BY StoreNbr,StoreName,Date WITH ROLLUP;
```

```php
$report = array();
while($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if ($row['StoreName'] === null) {
        // Skip this row.
        // It contains total sales grouped by StoreNbr 
        // (or not grouped if StoreNbr === null).
        continue;
    }
    $storeIndex = $row['StoreNbr'] . ':' . $row['StoreName'];
    if (!isset($report[$storeIndex])) {
        $report[$storeIndex] = $dateIndexedArray;
        $report[$storeIndex]['StoreNbr']  = $row['StoreNbr'];
        $report[$storeIndex]['StoreName'] = $row['StoreName'];
    }
    if ($row['Date'] === null) {
        // This row contains total sales grouped by StoreNbr & StoreName
        $report[$storeIndex]['TotalSales'] = $row['Sales']
    } else {
        $report[$storeIndex][$row['Date']] = $row['Sales'];
    }
}
```

Please note that i've never used `WITH ROLLUP`. So you might need to adjust the code.

Comment: Thank you for that! Is there any chance I could get the totals in this loop ? for example
    '1113:Store2' => [
            'StoreNbr'  => 1113,
            'StoreName' => 'Store2',
            '2016-01-16' => 112.44,
            '2016-01-17' => 56.61,
            'totals' => 169.05
        ]

Comment: @IoannisKokkinis, check the update. Would be nice if you give me some feedback after testing it because i've never tried that.

Comment: This ROLUP is amazing.. never used it before. It is just that it gets me as many NULL rows as the group by items in the clause. I am working on it and will come back when ready.